# IFS=: leads to different behavior while looping over colon-separated values

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, ifs

#### Experiment 1

Here is my first script in file named `foo.sh`.

```
IFS=:
for i in foo:bar:baz
do
    echo $i
done
```

This produces the following output.

```
$ bash foo.sh
foo bar baz
```

#### Experiment 2

This is my second script.

```
IFS=:
for i in foo:bar:baz
do
    unset IFS
    echo $i
done
```

This produces the following output.

```
$ bash foo.sh
foo:bar:baz
```

#### Experiment 3

This is my third script.

```
IFS=:
var=foo:bar:baz
for i in $var
do
    echo $i
done
```

This produces the following output.

```
$ bash foo.sh
foo
bar
baz
```

Why is the output different in all three cases? Can you explain the
rules behind the interpretation of IFS and the commands that leads to
this different outputs?

Comment: You're conflating two different things: The behavior of the `for i in foo:bar:baz`, and the behavior of the unquoted expansion in `echo $i`. If you were testing with, say, `echo "$i"`, then that would let you isolate only the behavior of `for i in foo:bar:baz` (and how it *doesn't change at all* based on `IFS`), which is arguably the core of your question -- whereas by contrast, a question that *only* asked about behavior of `echo $i` with no surrounding `for` would be a simple dupe, which could be answered by a pointer to questions and answers that already exist.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found this a very interesting experiment.
Thank you for that.

---

To understand what is going on,
the relevant section from `man bash` is this:

> ```
>   Word Splitting
>       The  shell  scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitu-
>       tion, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double  quotes
>       for word splitting.
> ```

The key is the *"results of ..."* part, and it's very subtle.
That is, word splitting happens on the *result of certain operations*,
as listed there: the result of parameter expansion,
the result of command substitution, and so on.
Word splitting is not performed on string literals such as `foo:bar:baz`.

Let's see how this logic plays out in the context of your examples.

#### Experiment 1

```
IFS=:
for i in foo:bar:baz
do
    echo $i
done
```

This produces the following output:

> ```
> foo bar baz
> ```

No word splitting is performed on the literal `foo:bar:baz`,
so it doesn't matter what is the value of `IFS`,
as far as the `for` loop is concerned.

Word splitting is performed after parameter expansion on the value of `$i`,
so `foo:bar:baz` is split to 3 words,
and passed to `echo`, so the output is `foo bar baz`.

#### Experiment 2

```
IFS=:
for i in foo:bar:baz
do
    unset IFS
    echo $i
done
```

This produces the following output:

> ```
> foo:bar:baz
> ```

Once again,
no word splitting is performed on the literal `foo:bar:baz`,
so it doesn't matter what is the value of `IFS`,
as far as the `for` loop is concerned.

Word splitting is performed after parameter expansion on the value of `$i`,
but since `IFS` was unset,
its default value is used to perform the split,
which is `<space><tab><newline>`.
But since `foo:bar:baz` doesn't contain any of those,
it remains intact, so the output is `foo:bar:baz`.

#### Experiment 3

```
IFS=:
var=foo:bar:baz
for i in $var
do
    echo $i
done
```

This produces the following output:

> ```
> foo
> bar
> baz
> ```

*After the parameter expansion of `$var`*,
word splitting is performed using the value of `IFS`,
and so `for` has 3 values to iterate over, `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`.
The behavior of `echo` is trivial here,
the output is one word per line.

---

The bottomline is: word splitting is not performed on literal values.
Word splitting is only performed on the result of certain operations.

This is not all that surprising.
A string literal is much like an expression written enclosed in double-quotes, and you wouldn't expect word splitting on `"..."`.

Comment: Great answer, this should get the bounty! Similar question/answer here as well: [Word splitting in Bash with printf and with IFS set to non-whitespace character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43163356/686260).